# Pandas: How to export each dataframe row, into a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame, I want to iterate through each row and append the current row into a new dataframe.
This is an example of the original dataframe: (without the indexes)

```
ISBN          Book-Author       Year-Of-Publication     Keywords
...
...
0330353349    Minette Walters         1997           [ice, house, tv, tie, edition]
```

When I try to do it, the result (new DataFrame) comes out like this:

```
ISBN      0330353349
Book-Author       Minette Walters
Year-Of-Publication     1997
Keywords    [ice, house, tv, tie, edition]
```

Which is basically inverted. I tried to use transpose() but nothing changes.

This is the general idea of my code:

```
for index, row in temp_df.iterrows():
    temp_row = temp_df.loc[index,:]
    row_transposed = temp_row.transpose()
    # call xyz function for row_transposed
```

And it is a problem because my xyz function works only when passing a singe-row dataframe.

Comment: temp_row is instance of `pd.Series` you would need `.to_frame().T` But surely there is a better solution. how about your function?

Comment: If you want to merge *all* rows from `df2` into `df1` and both DataFrames have the same column names, you can simply use `pd.concat([df1, df2])`.

Comment: @ansev That worked! I didn't realize that, got a better understanding now, thank you!

Comment: You should fix your `xyz` function then? Looping through a DataFrame is very inefficient and creating one line DataFrames even more... At the very least, consider using something like `df.apply(xyz, axis=1)` but best is really rethink `xyz` if you can.

Comment: It was for a uni assignment and I sadly didn't have time to re-think the xyz function, because of my deadline. However, I can see why it's not the optimal solution. Thank you for your help.